# Custom URL in AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud-hosting, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

AWS Elastic Beanstalk suggests using a URL in the following format: `https://{appname}.elasticbeanstalk.com/`

But I need to change it to my own URL, something like `https://tarta.ai`

How to do it?

Answer (score 41):

**Note**: I use Amazon Route53 for my domain.

---

I know this is old question but since I just done this process for one of my apps, I decided to share it here which may help others too. Here's the steps I've gone through

1. Login to your AWS Account
2. Go to your EC2 Panel and select your region
3. Select Load Balancer from left navigation menu
4. Found Load Balancer which related to your Beanstalk App
5. In Description Tab grab Hosted Zone ID
6. Open Route53 Panel
7. Select your domain hosted zone
8. Add A Record for `.example.com`
9. Select Alias option to Yes
10. Search for your Load Balancer related to you app
11. Confirm it's Hosted Zone ID with what you grabbed in step 5
12. Do steps 8-11 for `www.example.com` as well.

---

**References**

- http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customdomains.html
- http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2011/05/moving-ahead-with-amazon-route-53.html

Comment: I dont see the option of load balancer

Comment: Would you please explain at which step you have problem?

Comment: Hi @Qorbani, I already did what you post, but it's still not working. Could be that it takes a while to map the new address or should it be visible instantly? I also deleted the cache on my browser, Thank you!

Comment: I can take upto 24 hours, but should be no more than 1 hour

Answer (score 9):

Use Amazon [Route53.](http://aws.amazon.com/route53/) ELBs, including those generated with ElasticBeanstalk, are assigned CNAMEs. You can't just point your top-level domain at a CNAME, as it violates the RFC. You could point a CNAME record like `http://www.example.com` at it, but that still won't respond at `http://example.com`. It's an irritating problem; for example, consider this [7-page thread on the AWS forum.](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=185427)

The easiest solution is Route53. It uses special apex records to map TLDs to ELBs, thus avoiding the problem entirely. You can also use an EIP'd public instance to forward traffic to the ELB, although [this raises scalability concerns.](http://shlomoswidler.com/2011/01/aws-auto-scaling-and-elb-with-reliable-root-domain-handling.html)