# Creating Subdomain for Elastic Beanstalk Environment outside AWS and Route 53

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-elb

I have a django apllication that I deployed on EB. The app only contains my backend endpoint that connect to database. I have encountered a CORS error when connecting to the endpoint from my React app because it only uses http. In order to use https, I tried to use a subdomain for my EB environment.

I followed different tutorials from different articles like configuring load balancer, using Route 53 hosted zone and etc. until I encountered this thread on stackoverflow [External subdomain pointing to Elastic Beanstalk environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66903629/external-subdomain-pointing-to-elastic-beanstalk-environment)

I follow the instructions, it said that theres no need to use route 53 and just create a CNAME on my DNS. But when I visited my subdomain, it returns Bad Request (400). When I tried to visit the URL provided by AWS EB, the app is fully working, it only returns error when I am using the subdomain.

Procedures I did.
I have domain name outside aws, the main domain serves another app. I set subdomain (e.g.test.domain.com) with the value of my eb environment url from AWS (e.g. test-environment.us-east-2.elasticbeanstalk.com
)

curl -i result of the subdomain

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Date: Thu, 05 Aug 2021 02:40:23 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Server: nginx/1.20.0
Vary: Origin


<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bad Request (400)</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Bad Request (400)</h1><p></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So what's wrong? It seems it works.

Comment: @marcin, what is showing on the image is not my app Sir. I think it is auto-generated from elastic beanstalk itself. Then after a while it returns Bad Request (400) , but the app is working on my EB environment.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please describe exactly, in details, your setup, testing procedure, expected outcomes.

Comment: Did you `curl -i test.domain.com`? What exactly is the error?

Comment: @Marcin sorry I am a newbie with regards on this matter. I added the result on my question. Thank you

Comment: is the loadbalancer shared or managed by your EB environment configuration?

Comment: @Nathan I followed this tutorial on setting up the load balancer https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kvM-Tfa71eo

Comment: did you solve the problem? I am facing the same issue.